# Retrieve Xml and string data in JSON Format from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have created a WebAPI which i need to convert strings and Xml data into JSON resultset for my application. But what resultset i am getting is not the exact format what i want

**Below is my method**

```
 public string Index1(int? requestID)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;

            requestID = 453;
            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[ERNST_usp_GetRequest]", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;



            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = requestID;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //DataSet ds = new DataSet("Yo");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            //da.Fill(ds);
            da.Fill(dt);

            //string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
            string id = dt.Rows[0]["RequestId"].ToString();
            string guid = dt.Rows[0]["RequestGuid"].ToString();
            string requestXml = dt.Rows[0]["RequestXml"].ToString();
            string requestDate = dt.Rows[0]["RequestDate"].ToString();
            string responseXml = dt.Rows[0]["ResponseXml"].ToString();
            string responseDate = dt.Rows[0]["ResponseDate"].ToString();
            string documentDetails = dt.Rows[0]["DocumentTypeDetails"].ToString();
            string showRecInfo = dt.Rows[0]["ShowRecordingInfo"].ToString();
            string isOfficeDetailsRequest = dt.Rows[0]["IsOfficeDetailsRequest"].ToString();
            string UserId = dt.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();
            string isSaved = dt.Rows[0]["IsSaved"].ToString();
            string name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();

            XmlDocument xmlreq = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDocument xmlres = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            // xml.LoadXml(s);
            xmlreq.LoadXml(requestXml);
            xmlres.LoadXml(responseXml);
            xmldoc.LoadXml(documentDetails);
                 string reqjson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlreq, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
            string resjson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlres, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
            string docjson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmldoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.ColumnName == "RequestXml")
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, reqjson);
                    }
                    else if (col.ColumnName == "ResponseXml")
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, resjson);
                    }
                    else if (col.ColumnName == "DocumentTypeDetails")
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, docjson);
                    }
                    else
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            con.Close();
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

}

**I am getting this result**

```
[{"RequestId":453,"RequestGuid":"a81b5878-6214-44b4-8888-aab46ce48adf","RequestXml":"{\"App\":\"B\",\"Authentication\":{\"UserID\":\"\",\"Password\":\"\"},\"TransactionDate\":\"1/27/2016\",\"TransactionCode\":\"150\",\"Property\":{\"Page\":\"AL005\",\"City\":null,\"County\":null,\"State\":\"AL\",\"EstimatedValue\":\"150000\",\"MortgageAmount\":null,\"OriginalDebtAmount\":null,\"UnpaidPrincipalBalance\":null,\"OriginalMortgageDate\":null,\"StateQuestions\":{\"Q1\":\"0\",\"Q2\":\"0\",\"Q3\":\"0\",\"Q4\":\"1\",\"Q5\":\"0\",\"Q6\":\"0\",\"Q7\":\"0\",\"Q8\":\"0\",\"Q9\":\"0\",\"Q10\":\"0\",\"Q11\":\"0\",\"Q12\":\"0\",\"Q13\":\"0\",\"Q14\":\"0\",\"Q15\":\"0\",\"Q16\":\"0\",\"Q17\":\"0\",\"Q18\":\"0\",\"Q19\":\"0\",\"Q20\":\"0\",\"Q21\":\"0\",\"V1\":\"0\",\"V2\":\"0\",\"V3\":\"0\",\"V4\":\"0\"}},\"NumberOfPages\":{\"Mortgage\":null,\"Deed\":\"1\"},\"Assignment\":{\"Pages\":null,\"NumberOfAssignments\":null},\"Release\":{\"Pages\":null,\"NumberOfReleases\":null},\"DataSource\":\"P\"}","RequestDate":"\/Date(1264562248000)\/","ResponseXml":"{\"Request\":{\"TransactionID\":\"2847578_20100127.114729700\",\"Page\":\"AL005\",\"City\":null,\"County\":null,\"State\":\"AL\",\"TransactionCode\":\"100\",\"DeedNumberOfPages\":\"1\",\"MortgageNumberOfPages\":null,\"MortgageAmount\":null,\"OriginalDebtAmount\":null,\"UnpaidPrincipalBalance\":null,\"EstimatedValue\":\"150000\",\"Title\":null,\"TitleAmount\":null,\"OriginalTitleAmount\":null,\"OriginalMortgageDate\":null,\"AssignmentPages\":null,\"AssignmentNumber\":null,\"ReleasePages\":null,\"ReleaseNumber\":null,\"StateQuestions\":{\"Q1\":\"0\",\"Q2\":\"0\",\"Q3\":\"0\",\"Q4\":\"1\",\"Q5\":\"0\",\"Q6\":\"0\",\"Q7\":\"0\",\"Q8\":\"0\",\"Q9\":\"0\",\"Q10\":\"0\",\"Q11\":\"0\",\"Q12\":\"0\",\"Q13\":\"0\",\"Q14\":\"0\",\"Q15\":\"0\",\"Q16\":\"0\",\"Q17\":\"0\",\"Q18\":\"0\",\"Q19\":\"0\",\"Q20\":\"0\",\"Q21\":\"0\",\"V1\":\"0\",\"V2\":\"0\",\"V3\":\"0\",\"V4\":\"0\"}},\"Data\":{\"Refacts\":{\"STABBR\":\"AL\",\"ROFFICE\":\"Autauga County\",\"COUNTY\":\"Autauga\",\"PAGE\":\"AL005\",\"PAGEKEY2\":\"AL020\",\"PHONE\":\"334-361-3731\",\"EXT\":null,\"FAX\":\"334-361-3740\",\"TIMEZONE\":\"CST\",\"ATTN\":\"Attn: Real Estate Recording\",\"DEPT\":\"Autauga County Judge of Probate\",\"PAYEE\":\"Autauga County Judge of Probate\",\"FEEPAY\":\"Required from remitters with previous history of bad checks.\",\"MADDR1\":\"176 W. 5th St.\",\"MADDR2\":null,\"MCITYST\":\"Prattville, AL 36067-3041\",\"MCITY\":\"Prattville\",\"MZIP\":\"36067-3041\",\"CADDR1\":\"176 W. 5th St.\",\"CADDR2\":null,\"CCITYST\":\"Prattville, AL 36067\",\"CCITY\":\"Prattville\",\"CZIP\":\"36067\",\"HOURS\":\"8:30AM-4:30PM\",\"TITLE\":\"County Judge of Probate\",\"TAT\":\"3 days\",\"TATNUM\":\"3\",\"DEED\":\"Direct/Indirect\",\"MORTGAGE\":\"Direct/Indirect\",\"COUNTYFIPS\":\"01001\",\"LASTUPD\":\"05/31/09\",\"DEEDDESC\":\"Deed/Deed of Trust/Mortgage\",\"DEEDFEE\":\"11\",\"DEEDCD\":\"11\",\"MORTDESC\":null,\"MORTFEE\":\"0\",\"MORTCD\":\"0\",\"AMFEE\":\"11\",\"AMCD\":\"11\",\"ASSNDESC\":\"Assignment\",\"ASSNFEE\":\"11\",\"ASSNCD\":\"11\",\"SATDESC\":\"Release/Satisfaction\",\"SATFEE\":\"11\",\"SATCD\":\"11\",\"ADDPGFEE\":\"3\",\"ADDPGCD\":\"24\",\"NONSTDFEE\":\"0\",\"NSCD\":\"0\",\"SMPRNTFEE\":\"0\",\"SMPRCD\":\"0\",\"LEGALFEE\":\"11\",\"LEGALCD\":\"11\",\"ADDTYPE1\":\"3\",\"ADDFEE1\":\"1\",\"ADDCD1\":\"223\",\"ADDTYPE2\":\"59\",\"ADDFEE2\":\"2.5\",\"ADDCD2\":\"100\",\"ADDTYPE3\":\"19\",\"ADDFEE3\":\"88.88\",\"ADDCD3\":\"0\",\"ADDTYPE4\":\"0\",\"ADDFEE4\":\"0\",\"ADDCD4\":\"0\",\"ADDTYPE5\":\"0\",\"ADDFEE5\":\"0\",\"ADDCD5\":\"0\",\"ADDTYPE6\":\"0\",\"ADDFEE6\":\"0\",\"ADDCD6\":\"0\",\"DESC1\":\"Deed Tax\",\"TAX1\":\"0.5\",\"TAX1CD\":\"97\",\"DESC2\":\"Mortgage Tax\",\"TAX2\":\"0.15\",\"TAX2CD\":\"98\",\"DESC3\":null,\"TAX3\":\"0\",\"TAX3CD\":\"0\",\"TAXNOTE\":\"ALTAX\",\"SEARCH\":\"N\",\"COPYFEE\":\"1\",\"COPYCD1\":\"11\",\"COPYFEE2\":\"1\",\"COPYCD2\":\"24\",\"CERTFEE\":\"3\",\"CERTCD\":\"32\",\"DOCSYSTEM\":\"Book \u0026 Page\",\"DSEXAMPLE\":\"RLPY 900 Page 1000\",\"FEENOTE1\":\"AL005\",\"FEENOTE2\":\"ALEXT\",\"FEENOTE3\":null,\"RECNOTE1\":null,\"RECNOTE2\":null,\"RECNOTE3\":\"ALERR\",\"BLASSN\":\"Y\",\"BLREL\":\"Y\",\"ARNUM\":\"0\",\"ARTYPE\":null,\"DOCRETURN\":null,\"SASE\":\"R\",\"SUBDOCS\":\"N\",\"LDIND\":\"dm\",\"LDDESC\":\"Legal description required only with deeds and mortgages (trust deeds).\",\"CAPFEE\":\"0\",\"CAPCD\":\"0\",\"C1\":null,\"PIN\":\"y\",\"PINNAME\":\"PIN\",\"PINON\":\"a\",\"PINFORM\":null,\"PINNOTE\":null,\"WEBADDR\":\"None\",\"FIPSB\":\"01001\",\"UPDATED\":\"Notes\"}},\"Display\":{\"Calculation\":{\"Deed\":{\"Fee\":\"11\",\"Tax\":\"150\",\"RoundedDeed\":\"150000\",\"StateTax\":\"150.00\",\"CountyTax\":\"0.00\",\"CityTax\":\"0.00\",\"BuyerSplit\":\"0\",\"BuyerSplitRate\":\"0\",\"SellerSplit\":\"0\",\"SellerSplitRate\":\"0\",\"BuyerSellerNote\":null,\"RoundedDeedState\":\"0\",\"RoundedDeedCounty\":\"0\",\"RoundedDeedCity\":\"0\"},\"HUD\":{\"HUDLine\":[{\"LineNumber\":\"1109\",\"LineDescription\":\"Lenders Coverage\",\"TitlePremium\":\"0\"},{\"LineNumber\":\"1201\",\"LineDescription\":\"Recording fees\",\"DeedAmount\":\"11\",\"MortgageAmount\":\"0\",\"ReleaseAmount\":\"0\"},{\"LineNumber\":\"1202\",\"LineDescription\":\"City/County tax/stamps\",\"DeedAmount\":\"0.00\",\"MortgageAmount\":\"0\",\"ReleaseAmount\":\"0\"},{\"LineNumber\":\"1203\",\"LineDescription\":\"State tax/stamps\",\"DeedAmount\":\"150.00\",\"MortgageAmount\":\"0\",\"ReleaseAmount\":\"0\"},{\"LineNumber\":\"1204\",\"LineDescription\":\"Miscellaneous fee/taxes\",\"DeedAmount\":\"0\",\"MortgageAmount\":\"0\",\"ReleaseAmount\":\"0\"},{\"LineNumber\":\"1205\",\"LineDescription\":\"Miscellaneous fee/taxes\",\"DeedAmount\":\"0\",\"MortgageAmount\":\"0\",\"ReleaseAmount\":\"0\"}]},\"MortgageFee\":\"0\",\"MortgageTax\":\"0\",\"MortgageNote\":null,\"DeedFee\":\"11\",\"DeedTax\":\"150\",\"DeedNote\":null,\"Assumptions\":{\"Assumption\":[\"THERE ARE TWO OR FEWER GRANTORS AND TWO OR FEWER GRANTEES ON THE DOCUMENT.\",\"NOTE MARITAL STATUS OF INDIVIDUAL GRANTORS ON DEEDS AND MORTGAGES.\",\"THE LENDER IS CUSTOMARILY RESPONSIBLE FOR PAYMENT OF THE MORTGAGE TAX.\"]}},\"RecordingWorksheet\":{\"Office\":{\"County\":null,\"CourierAddress1\":\"176 W. 5th St.\",\"CourierAddress2\":null,\"CourierCityStateZIP\":\"Prattville, AL 36067\",\"Department\":\"Attn: Real Estate Recording\",\"Fax\":\"334-361-3740\",\"Jurisdiction\":\"Autauga County Judge of Probate\",\"MailingAddress1\":\"176 W. 5th St.\",\"MailingAddress2\":null,\"MailingCityStateZIP\":\"Prattville, AL 36067-3041\",\"MoneyOrder\":\"Required from remitters with previous history of bad checks.\",\"Payee\":\"Autauga County Judge of Probate\",\"Phone\":\"334-361-3731\",\"PhoneExt\":null,\"RecordingOffice\":\"Autauga County\",\"TimeZone\":\"CST\",\"Website\":\"None\"},\"BasicRecordingFees\":{\"Heading\":\"BASIC RECORDING FEES:\",\"Fee\":[{\"Description\":\"Deed/Deed of Trust/Mortgage\",\"Amount\":\"$11.00\",\"Label\":\"for the first page\"},{\"Description\":\"Amendment/Modification\",\"Amount\":\"$11.00\",\"Label\":\"for the first page\"},{\"Description\":\"Assignment\",\"Amount\":\"$11.00\",\"Label\":\"for the first page\"},{\"Description\":\"Release/Satisfaction\",\"Amount\":\"$11.00\",\"Label\":\"for the first page\"},{\"Description\":\"Power of Attorney\",\"Amount\":\"$11.00\",\"Label\":\"for the first page\"}]},\"AdditionalRecordingFees\":{\"Heading\":\"ADDITIONAL RECORDING FEES:\",\"Fee\":[{\"Description\":\"Additional pages and attachments\",\"Amount\":\"$3.00\",\"Label\":\"per additional page\"},{\"Description\":\"Indexing fee\",\"Amount\":\"$1.00\",\"Label\":\"per name over two for each party (note 1)\"},{\"Description\":\"Multiple assignments or releases\",\"Amount\":\"$2.50\",\"Label\":\"per reference after first\"},{\"Description\":\"Pages larger than 8 1/2\\\" by 14\\\"\",\"Amount\":\"Not Accepted\",\"Label\":null}]},\"RecordingFeeNotes\":{\"Heading\":\"RECORDING FEE NOTES:\",\"Note\":[\"1. Husband and wife with the same surname count as one name, but a wife who hyphenated her name counts as a separate name.\",\"2. If the mortgage is exempt from mortgage tax, add $3.00 to mortgage recording fee. The additional $3.00 recording fee is included in the calculated recording fee for a mortgage if the answer to the question regarding the Federal Credit Union is \\\"yes\\\".\"]},\"Taxes\":{\"Heading\":\"TRANSFER AND FINANCING FEES/TAXES:\",\"Tax\":[{\"Description\":\"Deed Tax\",\"Amount\":\"$0.50\",\"Label\":\"per $500 or fraction thereof of consideration\"},{\"Description\":\"Mortgage Tax\",\"Amount\":\"$0.15\",\"Label\":\"per $100 or fraction thereof financed\"}],\"Note\":\"Before recording a deed, obtain a slip showing value of property from Revenue Commissioner to use in tax computation.\"},\"Searches\":{\"Heading\":\"SEARCHES, COPIES AND CERTIFICATION:\",\"Note\":\"This office does not perform any searches of real estate records.\",\"Fee\":[{\"Description\":\"Copies made by office\",\"Amount\":\"$1.00\",\"Label\":\"per page\"},{\"Description\":\"Certification (in addition to copy fees)\",\"Amount\":\"$3.00\",\"Label\":\"per document\"}]},\"RecordingNotes\":{\"Heading\":\"DOCUMENTATION/RECORDING NOTES:\",\"Note\":[\"Blanket assignments are accepted.\",\"Blanket releases are accepted.\",\"Originals of real estate documents are always returned after recording.\",\"A self addressed stamped return envelope of the proper size is required.\",\"In subsequent related documents, only reference (book/page, doc#, etc.) to the original document is required.\",\"Index for Deeds: Direct/Indirect\",\"Index for Mortgages: Direct/Indirect\",\"Common document errors include fee incorrect, \\\"prepared by\\\" statement missing, notarial certificate incomplete or seal missing, grantee address missing from deed, reference to original document missing, and marital status of grantor missing from deed.\",\"This office reports a document turnaround time of 3 days\",\"Most recent annual document volume reported by this office: 12286\"],\"DocSystem\":\"Book \u0026 Page\",\"DSExample\":\"RLPY 900 Page 1000\"},\"LDDescription\":\"Legal description required only with deeds and mortgages (trust deeds).\",\"PIN\":{\"PINRequired\":\"PIN required on all real estate documents to be recorded.\"},\"OnlineSearching\":\"None\",\"ConformedCopies\":\"This office does not provide Conformed Copies.\",\"UCCOfficials\":{\"Heading\":\"RECORDING OFFICE STAFF:\",\"Official\":[{\"Description\":\"Head Official\",\"Name\":\"Alfred Q Booth\",\"Title\":\"Judge of Probate\"},{\"Description\":\"Other Official\",\"Name\":\"Kathy Evans\",\"Title\":\"Chief Clerk\"},{\"Description\":\"Other Official\",\"Name\":\"Cindy Holland\",\"Title\":\"Supervisor of Recording\"},{\"Description\":\"Other Official\",\"Name\":\"Shannon Smith\",\"Title\":\"Tag \u0026 Title Supervisor\"},{\"Description\":\"Other Official\",\"Name\":\"Mary Ann Keith\",\"Title\":\"Asst Chief Clerk\"}]}},\"DocumentLinks\":{\"Link\":[{\"Label\":\"Charts\",\"URL\":\"http://www.ernstpublishing.com/extsubscribers/ResourceDownload.asp?username=ctiuser\u0026password=dataplus\u0026action=authenticate\u0026doc=repdfs/intros/allcharts.pdf\"},{\"Label\":\"State Forms\",\"URL\":\"http://www.ernstpublishing.com/extsubscribers/ResourceDownload.asp?username=ctiuser\u0026password=dataplus\u0026action=authenticate\u0026doc=repdfs/illustrations/ALf.pdf\"}]}}}","ResponseDate":"\/Date(1264562248000)\/","DocumentTypeDetails":"{\"PageRec\":\"AL005\",\"State\":\"AL\",\"County\":\"Autauga County\",\"CityTown\":null,\"Zip\":null,\"ShowRecordingInfo\":\"true\",\"Deed\":{\"Checked\":\"True\",\"Pages\":\"1\",\"ConsiderationAmount\":\"150000\"},\"MortgageDeed\":{\"Checked\":\"False\",\"Pages\":null,\"NewDebtAmount\":null},\"MortgageRefi\":{\"Checked\":\"False\",\"Pages\":null,\"NewDebtAmount\":null,\"OriginalDebt\":null,\"UnpaidDebt\":null},\"Assignment\":{\"Checked\":\"False\",\"Pages\":null,\"Assignments\":null},\"ReleaseSatisfaction\":{\"Checked\":\"False\",\"Pages\":null,\"ReleasesSatisfactions\":null},\"Questions\":{\"Question\":{\"Number\":\"Q4\",\"Category\":\"Deed\",\"Type\":\"bool\",\"QuestionText\":\"Are the deed and mortgage being recorded at the same time?\",\"Answer\":\"1\"}}}","ShowRecordingInfo":true,"IsOfficeDetailsRequest":false,"UserId":8515,"IsSaved":true,"Name":"saving test check no link to ODP"}]
```

**But what result Format i want should be like without "/"**

```
[
    {
        "RequestId": 453,
        "RequestGuid": "a81b5878-6214-44b4-8888-aab46ce48adf",
        "ShowRecordingInfo": true,
        "IsOfficeDetailsRequest": false,
        "UserId": 8515,
        "IsSaved": true,
        "Name": "saving test check no link to ODP",
        "DocumentTypeDetails": {
            "PageRec": "AL005",
            "State": "AL",
            "County": "Autauga County",
            "CityTown": null,
            "Zip": null,
            "ShowRecordingInfo": "true",
            "Deed": {
                "Checked": "True",
                "Pages": "1",
                "ConsiderationAmount": "150000"
            },
            "Amend": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": "1",
                "ConsiderationAmount": "150000"
            },
            "MortgageDeed": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "NewDebtAmount": null
            },
            "MortgageMod": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "NewDebtAmount": null
            },
            "MortgageRefi": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "NewDebtAmount": null,
                "OriginalDebt": null,
                "UnpaidDebt": null
            },
            "Assignment": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "Assignments": null
            },
            "ReleaseSatisfaction": {
                "Checked": "False",
                "Pages": null,
                "ReleasesSatisfactions": null
            },
            "poa":{
                "Checked":"False",
                "Pages":null
            },
            "Questions": {
                "Question": {
                    "Number": "Q4",
                    "Category": "Deed",
                    "Type": "bool",
                    "QuestionText": "Are the deed and mortgage being recorded at the same time?",
                    "Answer": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        "RequestXml": {
            "App": "B",
            "Authentication": {
                "UserID": "",
                "Password": ""
            },
            "TransactionDate": "1/27/2016",
            "TransactionCode": "150",
            "Property": {
                "Page": "AL005",
                "City": null,
                "County": null,
                "State": "AL",
                "EstimatedValue": "150000",
                "MortgageAmount": null,
                "OriginalDebtAmount": null,
                "UnpaidPrincipalBalance": null,
                "OriginalMortgageDate": null,
                "StateQuestions": {
                    "Q1": "0",
                    "Q2": "0",
                    "Q3": "0",
                    "Q4": "1",
                    "Q5": "0",
                    "Q6": "0",
                    "Q7": "0",
                    "Q8": "0",
                    "Q9": "0",
                    "Q10": "0",
                    "Q11": "0",
                    "Q12": "0",
                    "Q13": "0",
                    "Q14": "0",
                    "Q15": "0",
                    "Q16": "0",
                    "Q17": "0",
                    "Q18": "0",
                    "Q19": "0",
                    "Q20": "0",
                    "Q21": "0",
                    "V1": "0",
                    "V2": "0",
                    "V3": "0",
                    "V4": "0"
                }
            },
            "NumberOfPages": {
                "Mortgage": null,
                "Deed": "1"
            },
            "Assignment": {
                "Pages": null,
                "NumberOfAssignments": null
            },
            "Release": {
                "Pages": null,
                "NumberOfReleases": null
            },
            "DataSource": "P"
        },

        }
    }
]
```

**How can i get the desired result**

Comment: Interesting.  Can you post your XML?  You may get some responses by tagging Newtonsoft as well, which is what's really doing the conversion.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth There is not particular Xml data for the whole...i am fetching data from db in which some columns will be in xml and some in string....string and xml i can convert in JSON seperately but the point is i want all of it in one single go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Web API, then you don't need System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer library. Change the return type of your Web API method to Model class and then simply return the model. Web API will automatically serialize it for you.

Comment: i dont have a model class..whatever Xml i get from database i simply have to send it ..so no point containing it in any model object